# Amazon Aurora MySQLでテーブルが更新されたことを検知する方法

Tags: mysql, aws, redis

Amazon Aurora MySQLにおいて、テーブルが更新されたかどうかを検知する方法を探っています。名案があれば教えて教えて頂きたいです。

目的：Elasticache(Redis)に保持しているクエリ結果のキャシュ更新
背景：テーブル更新をトリガーにして、キャッシュ更新を"アプリ外"から行いたい為

●期待している処理構成
[Aurora MySQL] -テーブル更新通知-> [Lambda] -キャシュ更新-> [Elasticache]

下記の案を検討していましたが、デメリットが多かった為に採用に至らなかったです。

検討していた案…TriggerからLambda起動
　内容：全テーブルにTriggerを仕込み、更新があった場合にLambda通知
　難点：全テーブルに仕込む必要がある。更新時、更新”行”毎にトリガーが起動されてしまう。

その他に期待している方法としては、MySqlのバイナリログ(トランザクションログ)から更新テーブルを検知できないか調査予定です。

よろしくお願いいたします。